# Method type definition inside object literal

Tags: typescript

I have an async function inside an object, I need to declare type like the following example:

```
interface Props {
  loading?: boolean | undefined;
  separator?: 'cell' | 'none';
  onRequest?: (requestProp: {
    pagination: {
      sortBy: string;
      descending: boolean;
      page: number;
      rowsPerPage: number;
    };
    filter: string;
  }) => void;
}

const myObj = {
  async myTest({ pagination }) {  // I need to assign myTest as Props['onRequest']
  let $id = this.id;
      /* consume $id and await */
      /* ... */
  },
  id: 521,
  result: '',
};
```

How can I declare the type of a method in an object literal?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution using [Parameters and NonNullable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) utilities.

```
    const myObj = {
      async myTest( {pagination} : Parameters<NonNullable<QTableProps['onRequest']> ) {  
      let $id = this.id;
          // pagination is extracted
          /* consume $id and await */
          /* ... */
      },
      id: 521,
      result: '',
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try one of these [options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ssl=16&ssc=2&pln=9&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArApsKBGGBeGBvAUDETAJYAmAXDAEwDMArADSHEC2AngCrLRUCGEdmGAwAFLgAOfAOYkwfKCXABfAJTYAfHhbFioSCAA2yAHSGQ00QAMoACxIRsMACS47D5VdUBuHbpj6EEam5pZWCCho6CbkTq4RqBgxZJ6MMKp+yvhZ+IGwCWjUTgS65FQAHOi0zLoc3LwwAkIiAGYArsKK4OJSsvJdYGra-nrgQcZmFtbujjiuAFIAygDyAHIm0ABOcrIt7KIzqp4+frqBwZNhBVDUyXG417fkqemnowYTodP2jrFzbj9ksdMtl8PgmsIYO1OkowDBWHw5KJ1CV3uMQlMAOQAWlxcCQiXQmIyuj4AHdEfkCVETHUeFAejI5ApYVR0GowWcxhcvji8Y9iX5yZT8ZEbrSuPTGX0WeA2RycgikaogA):

### Use arrow functions

```
const object1 = {
    id: 235,
    myTest: async ({pagination}) => {
        console.log(`this = ${this}`);
        console.log(`object1.id = ${object1.id}`, )
    }
}
```

In this style, `this` will be resolved to the `globalThis`, which in this case is `undefined` (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)).

```
[LOG]: "this = undefined" 
[LOG]: "object1.id = 235"
```

### Use regular functions

```
const object2 = {
    id: 813,
    myTest: async function({pagination}) {
        console.log(`this = ${JSON.stringify(this)}`);
        console.log(`object2.id = ${object2.id}`, )
        console.log(`this.id = ${this.id}`)
    }
}
```

Which will output:

```
[LOG]: "this = {"id":813}" 
[LOG]: "object2.id = 813" 
[LOG]: "this.id = 813"
```

---

#### Update to comment 1

First, I extracted the `RequestProp` type so that I could use it in function signatures. Then the rest is similar:

```
interface RequestProp {
  pagination: {
    sortBy: string;
    descending: boolean;
    page: number;
    rowsPerPage: number;
  };
  filter: string;
}

interface Props {
  loading?: boolean | undefined;
  separator?: "cell" | "none";
  onRequest?: (requestProp: RequestProp) => Promise<void>;
}

async function main() {
  const x: Props = {
    onRequest: async function (requestProp: RequestProp) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(requestProp, null, 2));
    },
  };

  if (x.onRequest) {
    const json = await x.onRequest({
      pagination: {
        sortBy: "x",
        descending: true,
        page: 1,
        rowsPerPage: 10,
      },
      filter: "xyz",
    });

    console.log(json);
  }
}

main();
```

Comment: How can I assign `Props['onRequest']` as the regular function type?

Comment: Hi @M.A.T, I updated the answer to explain how.